# How to Get Data from a Website Periodically (Android)

Tags: android, web-scraping, android-webview, intentservice

I have been working on a pet project for a bit now and have gotten it mostly working. It involves using a Webview to connect to a website (https if that matters), injecting Javascript to insert the login pin and password, and then getting the HTML of the page through an HttpUrlConnection, which I then parse on my own. The goal of this project is to automate getting the HTML every few hours to see if there are any changes and, if so, send a notification to the user. However, I ran into an issue where IntentServices cannot work with the onLoad method of a Webview, which kind of halts my project in its tracks. I also read in some places that a Webview must run in the UI thread while others contended it only needs to run on any single thread. When I attempt to run the IntentService, I get this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service app.mywork.sockettest.GetDataFromZangle@27de958e with Intent { cmp=app.mywork.sockettest/.GetDataFromZangle }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Message android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.obtainMessage()' on a null object reference

I have tried using HttpsUrlConnection for the whole thing, but that seems to run into some issues when I am trying to get the right cookies. So, I am wondering if there is any way to still use a Webview or something similar to it and still check the website every few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find an answer, so I just went through the process of managing the cookies on my own and using dozens of HttpUrlConnections.